# Reliably fix broken escape sequences in JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm getting some JSON for an outside source that can't be changed and apparently they don't understand the rules about escaping characters correctly in JSON string values. So they have a string value that might have tabs in it, for example, that should have been escaped and other invalid escape sequences like `\$`. I'm trying to parse this with JSON.Net but it keeps falling over on these sequences.

For example, the source might look something like this:

```
{
    "someRegularProp": 10,
    "aNormalString": "foo bar etc",
    "anInvalidString": "foo    <tab \$100"
}
```

and it's parsed with

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
```

So I can fix this specific case with something like:

```
json = json.Replace("\t", "").Replace("\\$", "$");  // note: in this case I'm fine with just stripping the tabs out
```

But is there a general way to fix these problems to remove invalid escape sequences before parsing? Because I don't know what other invalid sequences they might put in there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see general way. Obviously they are using bugged library or no library at all to generate this output and unless you explore more, all you can do is try as much output from them as possible to find all problems.

Perhaps make a script to generate as much output as possible and validate all of that, then you can be at least a bit more sure.